# Location of MvxBindingAvtivityView in MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross

To use Mvx.MvxBindableListView,I have to inferit my activity from  MvxBindingAvtivityView.
But I could't find this class anywhere in my Mvvmcross libraries.
I am using MvvmCross 3.1.1 which beta prerelease.
Which version of MvvmCross should I use?

Comment: @Stuart sir, How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mvx.MvxBindableListView is an old name, in MvvmCross v.3 this control is called Mvx.MvxListView

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxListView.cs